# What is the meaning of the word "cast" in 'a cannon can dominate us without an iron-monger to cast it'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Since it has lots of meanings in the English dictionary, I couldn't figure out which meaning is implied in the following context. Please help me out here to comprehend the meaning of the word ***cast***.

> After all, all law is made by people and interpreted by people and applied by people. It can no more rule us by itself, without human assistance, than a cannon can dominate us without an iron-monger to **cast** it and an artilleryman to load and fire it.

Also, it would be very nice if you can give me synonyms of the word ***cast***

Comment: Here ***cast*** refers to   :  *"make an object by pouring hot liquid, such as melted metal, into a shaped container where it becomes hard"*. From Cambridge Dictionary. - *"Field artillery cannon in Europe and the Americas were initially made most often of bronze, though later forms were constructed of cast iron and eventually steel."* From Wikipedia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast in this context means,

> an object made by shaping molten metal or similar material in a mold.

In simple words, it means something like "making it by shaping molten metal".

> After all, all law is made by people and interpreted by people and
>   applied by people. It can no more rule us by itself, without human
>   assistance, than a cannon can dominate us without an iron-monger
>   **making it by shaping molten metal** and an artilleryman to load and fire it.